# Do I need a handler?

Tags: android

I am working on an Android application and I have a question. I have a listener class that runs on back ground periodically and get data from my server. I want to add that data into a data structure in the main thread. In this case, I am not touch the main U.I. but I was wondering if I should use a handler to add the data into the data structure in the main thread. Or can I just set the data structure as static and access from the listener class to insert the data.  Which way should I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that (but there are others) is to use a list view and a cursor (it means you should use a database).
When you receive data from server (in your background thread), you add them to the database.
On the UI thread, you register a ContentObserver to be notified when data is added. When you're notified, you just have to requery

If you don't want to use a database, you can then send a Broadcast (see BroadcastReceiver) in which you can add data.